# Stuck in while loop with BufferedReader-java

Tags: java, while-loop, bufferedreader

I'm completely at a lose for why this isn't working. I've had similar loops before and they've worked fine.

```
try{
    text = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

    while ((lineOfText = text.readLine()) != null){
                StringTokenizer tokens = new     StringTokenizer(lineOfText," , .;:\"&!?-_\n\t12345678910[]{}()@#$%^*/+-");
                while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
                    countTotalWordsInDocument++;
                    String word = tokens.nextToken();
                    countTotalCharactersInAllWords = countTotalCharactersInAllWords + word.length();
                }
            }
            text.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("file not found");
        }
```

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? Are you seeing any error message or do you output anything to console?

Comment: what error do you get? what's in your input file?

Comment: NB When you get an exception, print *its* message. Don't make up your own.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, but the program continues to run indefinitely. I'm testing with a four line .txt file on my computer.

Comment: Remove all the loop body (all the tokens stuff) and try simply printing the `lineOfText`. If that works then your issue is with the tokenizer.

Comment: Well, that's definitely the problem. Thank you.